# Почему при изменении массива и слайса переданных в функцию у них разное поведение?

Tags: golang

Вычитал на go.dev что структура slice имеет 3 поля: указатель на массив, len, cap.
Но как устроен обычный массив я так и не нашел но подозреваю что он состоит из указателя и len.

Также мне известно что при передаче данных в функцию то они просто копируются (без явного указания что этого указатель и при этом это не map)

У меня возник вопрос, что будет если передать массив и слайс в функцию которая их изменит и после посмотреть содержимое изначальных переменных и оказалось что поведут они себя по разному

Пример:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    testSlice(slice)
    fmt.Println("slice main:", slice, unsafe.Pointer(&slice))

    array := [4]int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    testArray(array)
    fmt.Println("array main:", array, unsafe.Pointer(&array))
}

func testSlice(slice []int) {
    slice[0] = 0
    fmt.Println("slice func:", slice, unsafe.Pointer(&slice))
}

func testArray(array [4]int) {
    array[0] = 0
    fmt.Println("array func:", array, unsafe.Pointer(&array))
}
```

Данных код выведет следующий результат:

```
slice func: [0 2 3 4] 0xc000094078
slice main: [0 2 3 4] 0xc000094060
array func: [0 2 3 4] 0xc0000d0080
array main: [1 2 3 4] 0xc0000d0060
```

Видно что слайс изменился и в main функции, а массив показал ожидаемый результат. Я не нашел информации почему так происходит и хотел бы за одно посмотреть реализацию массива

Answer (score 1):

> Slice не хранит никаких данных, он просто описывает раздел базового
> массива.
> Изменение элементов slice изменяет соответствующие элементы
> базового массива.
> Другие фрагменты, которые используют один и тот же базовый массив,
> увидят эти изменения.

Вот тут все описано
https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/8

Comment: да, мне это известно. Мне интересно почему так не работает с массивом. Так как я думаю что они устроены также как строки (сишные массивы)

Answer (score 1):

Массив в Golang рассматривается как [структура с фиксированным числом полей одного и того же типа](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/dev.regabi/src/cmd/compile/internal-abi.md#memory-layout). Число элементов массива хранится в типе, поэтому массивам, в отличие от срезов, не нужно хранить размер и cap в значении. Значение массива - область памяти размером `размер_элемента*число_элементов`.

Массивы и большие структуры [передаются в функции через стек](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/dev.regabi/src/cmd/compile/internal-abi.md#function-call-argument-and-result-passing). Поэтому, когда вы в функции меняете элемент массива, то изменяете значение, расположенное на стеке. После возвращения из функции это изменение теряется.

Про реализацию. Как именно кодогенератор обрабатывает значения типа `[N]T`, я не нашел, но то, как устроена память для массива, можно узнать из пакета `reflect`. Метод [`Value.Index(int i)`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/reflect/value.go;l=1415) возвращает `i`-ый элемент массива, обёрнутый в объект типа [`Value`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/reflect/value.go;l=39):

```go
    case Array:
        tt := (*arrayType)(unsafe.Pointer(v.typ()))
        if uint(i) >= uint(tt.Len) {
            panic("reflect: array index out of range")
        }
        typ := tt.Elem
        offset := uintptr(i) * typ.Size()

        // Either flagIndir is set and v.ptr points at array,
        // or flagIndir is not set and v.ptr is the actual array data.
        // In the former case, we want v.ptr + offset.
        // In the latter case, we must be doing Index(0), so offset = 0,
        // so v.ptr + offset is still the correct address.
        val := add(v.ptr, offset, "same as &v[i], i < tt.len")
        fl := v.flag&(flagIndir|flagAddr) | v.flag.ro() | flag(typ.Kind()) // bits same as overall array
        return Value{typ, val, fl}
```

Другими словами, указатель на `i`-ый элемент массива равен `указатель_на_массив + i*размер_элемента`